# Jasper Reports - Exception when uploading report from studio to server?

Tags: java, jasper-reports, publish, jasperserver, jaspersoft-studio

I have Jasper Server 6.1.1 and Jasper Studio 6.1.1.

Here's my scenario:

I tried publishing a report from studio to server, and when I opened up the report on the server web application, the report came up as blank with a message saying 'The report is empty.'.

After a bit of googling, I found that my report needs to be published to the server with a data source in order for it to be viewed on the server web application.

So now, when I publish, I check 'Local Data Source'. I select a Datasource JDBC, give it a name ("test", for example) and I then "Import from Jaspersoft Studio", selecting the Data Adapter that I use for data in my report.

However, when I click finish, I get this error:

```
org.apache.http.client.HttpException: Internal Server Error           

at com.jaspersoft.studio.server.protocol.restv2.RESTv2ExceptionHandler.handleException(RESTv2ExceptionHandler.java:72)                
at com.jaspersoft.studio.server.protocol.restv2.ARestV2ConnectionJersey.toObj(ARestV2ConnectionJersey.java:52)   
at com.jaspersoft.studio.server.protocol.restv2.RestV2ConnectionJersey.addOrModifyResource(RestV2ConnectionJersey.java:515)                
at com.jaspersoft.studio.server.protocol.ProxyConnection.addOrModifyResource(ProxyConnection.java:314) 
at com.jaspersoft.studio.server.publish.Publish.publishResources(Publish.java:198)            
at com.jaspersoft.studio.server.publish.Publish.publish(Publish.java:67)   
at com.jaspersoft.studio.server.publish.wizard.Publish2ServerWizard$3.run(Publish2ServerWizard.java:302)         
at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121)
```

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0):

Do the following

1) Check if the data source created is correct

2) Check if a valid query is written or created in jasper server

3) Check if the data source is created for that query.

4) Check if the report design is correct

5) Check if query and data source are linked